# hidden field value contains [object object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am setting hidden field value in jquery script but hidden field returns values which contain [Object Object]

**Here are the values;**

"[object Object],22-Apr-2014"

**Script**

```
          var indx = 0;
          var hdfield = $('#hdlstVisitDates');
          var lst = $('#lstVisitDates');
          var options = $('#lstVisitDates option');
          $(options).each(function () {

              if (indx = 0) {
                  hdfield = $(this).val();
                  indx = 1;
              }
              else
              { hdfield = hdfield + ',' + $(this).val(); }
          });

          $('#hdlstVisitDates').val(hdfield);
```

Comment: Well you're assigning a jQuery object to `hdfield`, what else did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializing `hdfield` with `$('#hdlstVisitDates')` seems pointless since youre going to overwrite the value later, also you have `if (indx = 0) {` which will always evaluate to false it should be `if (indx == 0) {`

```
      var indx = 0;
      var hdfield;// = $('#hdlstVisitDates'); why do this?
      var lst = $('#lstVisitDates');
      var options = $('#lstVisitDates option');
      $(options).each(function () {

          if (indx == 0) {
              hdfield = $(this).val();
              indx = 1;
          }
          else
          { hdfield = hdfield + ',' + $(this).val(); }
      });

      $('#hdlstVisitDates').val(hdfield);
```

Comment: Thank you highlighting == :)

Answer (score 2):

```
// initialise hdfield with val()
var hdfield = $('#hdlstVisitDates').val();
```

otherwise hdfield will be the input element and the string concatenation will convert this to `[object Object]`